# How does the 'stop' mode in Proxmox' vzdump backup tool work?

Tags: backup, virtual-machines, proxmox, dump

So i'm currently using `vzdump` with the parameter `--mode stop`. In the description it says that the VM gets shut down before the actual backup starts and after the backup has been started the VM gets started again - if it has been running before.

Does `vzdump` create a temporary separate disk file of which the VM gets booted or how is it possible that the VM immediately starts again even though the backup process has not been finished yet and stop mode is getting described as having the highest consistency?

What if any changes occur in the VM while the backup job is still running?

Answer (score 0):

In all three modes, a snapshot of the VM is taken, and the snapshot is backed up. In the stop mode, the VM is shut down entirely before the snapshot is taken. After the snapshot is taken, the VM is restarted and the snapshot is backed up.